# Rake task which commit and push to repository

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, rake-task

Is there any way to create rake task that can commit changes and push them to remote repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do such task yourself:

```
task "commit_and_push" => :environment do
      system 'git commit -a -m "message"; git push'
end
```

But the rake is really slow, the quicker way is to create a shell script like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
git commit -a -m "$1"
git push
```